# Structuring A Script Using RCurl Package

Tags: r, rcurl

I've been using the command line to access API data from a vendor we use, but now the process has evolved to where I need to use R. I'm trying to use the RCurl package, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to structure the request.

The call in the command line looks like:

```
curl api.sample.io/users/scroll -u 'dG9rOmU5NGFjYTkwXzliNDFfNGIyMF9iYzA0XzU0NDg3MjE5ZWJkZDoxOjABCD=': -H 'Accept:application/json'
```

But I'm struggling to figure out how to put that together using the RCurl package.

FYI - Yes, I have read the RCurl manual.

Answer (score 0):

I considered down-voting since you did absolutely no research (you absolutely did not "read the RCurl manual") at all on either curl or processing web requests in R, but perhaps this will help others who at least did basic searches.

```
library(httr)

GET("http://api.sample.io/users/scroll",
    authenticate('dG9rOmU5NGFjYTkwXzliNDFfNGIyMF9iYzA0XzU0NDg3MjE5ZWJkZDoxOjABCD=', ""),
    accept_json())
```